# JPEG or Fractal to compress fingerprint images?

Tags: image, compression, jpeg, fingerprint, fractals

I am wondering, if it is desired to compress fingerprint images, what is the most suitable method among the compression methods: JPEG or fractal? Thanks

Comment: Why compress anyway? Storage is cheap.

Answer (score 0):

To compress fingerprint image, there's a dedicated compression algorithm WSQ : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavelet_scalar_quantization